# Redux form and react state update after second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

Hey guys so I have Screen where I have function

```
toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: !this.state.selectedItem})
}
```

then inside render form component

```
<SomeForm
    selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
    toggle={this.toggle}
    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
 />
```

inside the form I'm checking for different state values and updating the redux form value

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          toggle()
          if (selectedItem) {
            restInput.onChange('something')
          } else {
            restInput.onChange('')
          }
        }}
...
```

the redux form value and the state seem to be one step behind

Any idea how to debug this ? Thanks in forward

Comment: why you have selectedItem in redux & state. 
my solution would be to use redux data on both cases.

Comment: if you update the redux, so not needed to update local state of component and redux it will render twice.

Comment: Thanks guys that helped. Cheers!